# Hydra - Possible to follow redirects

Tags: asp.net, hydra

I'm trying to use Hydra on an ASP web application. Their login page uses the following method:

`site/Login`: username/password

If successful, I am redirect back to `site/Login` but with a newly set cookie, then redirected to `site/Home`

If authentication is not successful, the site shows an error message on `site/Login`

I've tried the following command:

`hydra <ip> http-post-form "site/Login.aspx:< args >:S=moved" -l test -p test`

However, this returns true for each user/pass combination. How can I make Hydra follow the redirection and work properly?

edit: It seems that Hydra is not able to create an SSL connection. I cannot see why it cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -S if you want to enable SSL

Comment: it might be helpful to also include a reference to the commandline options